# Can a single-core CPU ever achieve true concurrency?

Tags: concurrency

*"If you could sense the operation of a computer that is switching itself every few milliseconds amount dozens of tasks you would certainly agree that the computer seems to be performing these tasks simultaneously even though we know that the computer is interleaving the computations of the various tasks"*

- M.Ben-Ari, Principles of Concurrent Programming, 1982.

So on a single core CPU, it would be impossible for a single atomic operation to be carried out at the same time as another within the same system?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what an atomic operation means.

Comment: One needs to define "atomic operation" for a particular context. The answer changes depending upon the scale of such - and how such should be taken wrt to operations that visibly "act atomic".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, single-core CPUs can perform multiple operations simultaneously. For example, Pentium processors have multiple pipelines that operate concurrently. One could be doing an add while another is doing a load from memory. Of course you'd have no way to observe the effects of the simultaneous operations.

Further, architectures like the Pentium 4 are single-core, yet can have hyperthreading. This means that the different pipelines in a single core can not only be executing instructions concurrently, but those operations can be for separate threads. In other words, the CPU can issue instructions for different threads on the same clock tick.

Comment: The CPU front-end can issue instructions in parallel to multiple execution units in the back-end, yes. But 1 execution unit can only execute 1 instruction at a time, never 2 instructions at the same time - right? If I am wrong then I need prescription drugs.